# CMOS image sensor does not produce a picture, only vertical green/pink lines

Tags: image-sensor, mipi

We use the [AR0521](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/AR0521-1315682.pdf) CMOS image sensor and the [iMX8](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-processors/i-mx-applications-processors/i-mx-8-applications-processors:IMX8-SERIES) MPU for video recording.

75% of our PCBs don't have an image at the output, only green and pink vertical lines (see picture), but other PCBs work correctly.

[image: output image]

We did not find the difference between working and non-working boards. We already checked and tested:

- sensor power supply and MPU power supply from PMIC (within the limits allowed in the datasheet)
- MIPI CSI (send test image from sensor to MPU) and watch the MIPI signal on an oscilloscope (we checked only the presence of the signal itself, but not the signal edges, since the bandwidth of the oscilloscope does not allow this)
- MPU 24 MHz clock

Test pattern and image taken from a working and non-working board:
[image]  [image]

After cooling the boards in the freezer for half an hour, the non-working boards started working, but only until the reboot.
We also checked the installation on an x-ray and did not see any problems with the sensor and MPU.
Replacing the sensor with a new component did not help.

What could be the reason for the failure of the boards?

Comment: Sounds to me like it could be a layout issue. Slight differences in silicon and PCB set up let some of the boards work but not others. MIPI is pretty fussy; 0.15mm within a diff pair, 1.5mm between diff paris. Check the lenghts of every line first.

Comment: What is the scanning direction? If top-down, it looks like long streams of 1's and 0's coming out, would that explain anything? How does the power consumption compare to the working boards? Maybe there is latch-up if you reboot (powering up too quickly)? Are there on-chip configuration settings you might have missed?

Comment: We see very similar behavior with our AR0521 sensor board and TI SoC processor. Did you find the issue? If it were signal integrity related I would not expect to see noise free vertical stripes. Seems more likely a configuration issue where the AR0521 is not resetting consistently.

Answer (score 1):

> we checked only the presence of the signal itself, but not the signal edges, since the bandwidth of the oscilloscope does not allow this

So, you never verified the signal integrity... I guess that's where the problem is. But you'll need a better scope, and specific probing techniques.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that most often cause problems for image sensors that you you can check:

1. Verify the start-up sequence so that it is in line with the spec in the datasheet.
2. Verify the image sensors external clock.
3. Measure ripple and noise on the analog domain voltage. This voltage is usually extremely sensitive. It is best to use a very low noise LDO for this that is dedicated for the image sensor analog supply, and not a switching supply. Don't power anything else with this supply.
4. Verify the MIPI signaling with a scope setup for high speed differential signaling.

If all of this looks good then it might not be hardware related as such, and you should probably look for software configuration errors.

Answer (score 1):

In our case this imaging mode was caused by incorrect I2C writes to the sensor.

Once we corrected the register writes the output was correct.

Comment: bvwj - Thank you for writing an answer. To help readers understand your solution in more detail, can you [edit] the answer to add more information about which incorrect writes you corrected? || If the documentation meant that someone initially setup the sensor wrongly, perhaps other people made *exactly* the same mistake. Therefore giving more detail, if you can, about the specific mistake and solution may be extra helpful. TY